# Seeking an analytic solution to an SDE with curiously simple form

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

I would like to obtain an analytic solution to the following Stochastic Differential Equation (SDE) which looks like it could reduce to some standard form but I can't see it.   The equation is

$$dX = -\frac{1}{2} X^2 k^2 \; dt \; + \; X k \; dW.\quad\quad\quad\quad (\star)$$
where $dW$ is a Wiener increment (standard Brownian motion) and $k$ is a positive constant.  Also $X$ is positive in the circumstances I am considering.

This can be transformed with Ito's Lemma to give an alternative form
$$d\log X = -\frac{1}{2} X k^2 \; dt \; + \;  k \; dW\quad\quad\quad\quad (\dagger)$$

but neither of these SDEs are linear.  Equation $(\dagger)$ has shades of Ornstein-Uhlenbeck except that the LHS is $d\log X$ and not $dX$.

Any analytic solutions or possible approaches to a solution for either of these SDEs would be very gratefully received. Thank you.

[As a side question, is there a source that tables analytic solutions for SDEs in the same way as Gradshteyn and Ryzhik contains tables of integrals?  This would be very useful if it exists.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like the application of an Ito formula, as if $X=f(Y)$ where $dY=\sigma(Y) dW$ so that
$$
dX = f'(Y)σ(Y) dW+\tfrac12f''(Y)σ(Y)^2dt.
$$
So one would need
$$
f'(Y)σ(Y)=kX=kf(Y)\\
f''(Y)σ(Y)^2=-k^2f(Y)^2=-f'(Y)^2σ(Y)^2
$$
This then implies
$$
f'(y)=\frac1{c+y}, \\
f(y)=\ln(c+y)+d, \\
σ(y)=k(c+y)[\ln(c+y)+d]
$$
So the solution for the given SDE is "reduced" to the "simplified" SDE (fixing the constants to $c=1$, $d=0$ as example)
$$
dY=k(1+Y)\ln(1+Y) \, dW, ~~~ X=\ln(1+Y).
$$

Comment: Thanks Lutz, this does "simplify" the equation in the way I hoped; I am guessing that you quoted the "simplified" as this form may not make the solution any easier to obtain?

Comment: Yes to both, you now know that $Y$ is a martingale, but not much more.